# Minimizing instance variables in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm seeking brainstorming input for a Rails design issue I've run across.

I have simple Book reviews feature. There's a Book class, a User class, and a UserBook class (a.k.a., reviews and ratings).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_books
end

# (book_id, user_id, review data...)
class UserBook < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :book
end
```

In the corresponding book controller for the "show" book action, I need to load the book data along with the set of book reviews. I also need to find out whether the current user (if there is one) has contributed to those reviews.

I'm currently running two queries, Book.where(...) and UserBook.where(...), and placing the results into two separate objects passed on to the view. Now, while I could run a third query to find whether the user is among those reviews (on UserBook), I'd prefer to pull that from the @reviews result set. But do I do that in the controller, or in the view?

Also worth noting is that in the view I have to draw Add vs Update review buttons accordingly, with their corresponding ajax URLs. So I'd prefer to know it before I start looping through a result set.

If I detect this in the controller though, I'll need three instance variables passed in, which I understand is considered distasteful in Rails land. Not sure how to avoid this.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This smells like a case for has_many through, which is designed for cases where you want to access the data of a third table through an intermediate table (in this case, UserBook)

[Great explanation of has_many :through here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Might look something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_books
  has_many :users, through: :books
end
```

Then you can simply call

```
@user = User.find(x)
@user.user_books` # (perhaps aliased as `User.find(x).reviews`)
```

and

`@user.books`

to get a list of all books associated with the User.

This way, you can gain access to all of the information you need for a particular user with a single `@user` instance variable.

PS - You'll want to take a look at the concept of [Eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations), which will prevent you from making extraneous database calls while fetching all of this information.

Comment: This is a helpful suggestion. It's not exactly the answer I was looking for, but it puts me on the right track. I can use the through: mechanism to pull the book and its reviews at once, and then use your suggestion to extract the user's relationship to the same.